# How to differentiate between deploying releases vs snapshots

Tags: maven

I may be missing something extremely obvious, but I need some clarification regardless. I am about to begin development using maven and archiva. I added both servers + settings to settings.xml, and `distributionManagement` tags to the maven POM which I want to deploy.

I put references to both my internal snapshot repo, and my internal release repo in the POM. is there a specific maven command or option, which specifies to deploy as a SNAPSHOT, and NOT to both repos? Or if I do deploy, will it automatically push one copy to each repo?

Can someone clarify this?´

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If your `project.version` contains `SNAPSHOT` (e.g., 1.2-SNAPSHOT) and you execute `mvn deploy`, artifacts will be deployed to your snapshot repository. If it doesn't (e.g., 1.2) - they will be deployed to your release repository.

Comment: So in order to perform a "release", I determine the major/minor etc numbers myself? Or do I simply remove -SNAPSHOT from that line? Maven doesn't update them every time you do maven:release or whatever?

Comment: You can either do it manually or use [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/).

Comment: I highly suggest the maven-release-plugin since it will also create a tag for you and do all the tedious repetitive stuff

Comment: Tag is creating successfully but when I am running release:perform it failure due to error - The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory. Can you help me.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov sorry for bringing this back to life after 2 years but do you have a documentation for the behavior you have specified? I'm trying to find one.

Comment: @HarshilSharma I don't think so. If I had to find something, I would probably go directly to source code of deploy plugin.

Comment: To be more accurate, the ${project.version} must end with SNAPSHOT to be deployed to the snapshot repository. ( ie 3.5-SNAPSHOT will be deployed to snapshot repository, while 3.5-SNAPSHOT-TEST will go to the release repository )

Answer (score 35):

You can execute `mvn deploy`.

If your project version contains `-SNAPSHOT` as suffix, it will deploy into the repository configured under `distributionManagement.snapshotRepository`.

If your project doesn't contain `-SNAPSHOT` suffix, it will deploy into the repository configured under `distributionManagement.repository`.

However, I do recommend you to use `maven-release-plugin` to manage versioning and deployment. By running `mvn -B release:clean release:prepare release:perform`, in resume:

- the suffix `-SNAPSHOT` is removed from the version (e.g. `2.1-SNAPSHOT` -> `2.1`);
- the application is built so as to generate JAR files;
- the code is committed to your code repository (e.g. git) and tagged (e.g. `2.1`);
- the JAR is deployed into your release repository (not snapshot repo);
- the version is incremented and the suffix `-SNAPSHOT` is added (e.g. `2.2-SNAPSHOT`).

Answer (score 6):

For me putting a suffix: `SNAPSHOT` in `${project.version}` was not enough. I had to put a dash in front of it:`-SNAPSHOT` in order for maven to deploy it in the local snapshot repo.

Comment: Also, -SNAPSHOT is case sensitive. "-snapshot" will still be pushed as a release artifact.