# Versioning releases in Maven

Tags: maven, version-control, release

For current project I'm on version :

```
2.3.6-SNAPSHOT
```

If continue to use current naming structure there are 4 potential release version until version 2.4.0-RELEASE. To minimise risk of running out version numbers I plan to name next version :

```
2.3.6.1-RELEASE
```

Is this standard practice ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [maven - deploying releases vs snapshots, how to differentiate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461225/maven-deploying-releases-vs-snapshots-how-to-differentiate)

Comment: releases don't say `SNAPSHOT`, plain as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you run out of an infinite number of numbers?  What's wrong with 4.234 as a version number? Versioning has two meanings: technical, to define how big a change is and where in the functional set the version is; and marketing, which is used only to make purchasers feel good.

What does your versioning policy mean to you?